# Django Issue with multiple databases router | Connection not found

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to incorporate multiple databases. Allow me to break down what I've done so far:

#### Django Version:

I initiated the process by upgrading Django from version 4.2.1 to 5.0.1 while keeping my Python version constant at 3.10.2.

#### Apps:

Initially, my project had only two apps, but I've added a new one, resulting in a total of three. Importantly, there are no circular dependencies among them. All three apps have been properly added to the project's "Settings."

#### Settings:

In addition to the existing 'default' database, I introduced a new one named 'manager.' I adjusted the DATABASE_ROUTERS path accordingly in the project files.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.router-manager.ManagerRouter', 'routers.router-api.ApiRouter',]
```

#### Routers File:

Following the guidelines in the Django Documentation, I created a router file to manage the models for each app. Here's the configuration of my router file:

```
class ManagerRouter:
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the manager applications
and api applications.
"""

route_app_labels = {"distributor_api", "manager_api"}

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read manager_api and distributor_api models go to 
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return "manager"
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    All writes (i.e. any create or update) should be done to the 'db
    for write' which is set as 'db-distrib-manager'.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return "manager"
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    if(obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
       or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels):
        return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure that everything related to our apps goes into the 'db for
    write', otherwise put it in the default place.
    """
    if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return db == "manager"
    return None
```

#### Conclusion:

Despite successfully implementing the fundamental steps required to run Django with multiple databases, I'm encountering a peculiar error when executing the command `/manage.py migrate --database=manager --settings=myappsettings.dev`.

The traceback for this error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 58, in __getitem__
    return getattr(self._connections, alias)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 105, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"{self!r} object has no attribute {key!r}")
AttributeError: <asgiref.local.Local object at 0x104b3c6a0> object has no attribute 'manager'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/myophiomics/manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/myophiomics/manage.py", line 20, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 100, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 12, in check_database_backends
    conn = connections[alias]
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 61, in __getitem__
    raise self.exception_class(f"The connection '{alias}' doesn't exist.")
django.utils.connection.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection 'manager' doesn't exist.
```

In an attempt to understand the issue better, I ran the command `python3 manage.py diffsettings --all`. While I won't provide the entire output here, I'll share the relevant part related to the database. If needed, I can provide the complete output.

```
### DATABASES = {}
### DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
```

I've been grappling with this for two days now, and I'm struggling to determine whether it's due to misconfigurations, conflicts, or possibly a bug in the system.

Feel free to share any specific parts you'd like further clarification or modification on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain about the exact reason for this issue. However, I managed to resolve it by incorporating the following command into the manage.py file:

```
from django.db import connections

for alias in connections:
    print(alias)
```

I cannot pinpoint why, but executing this command seemed to compel Django to actively seek connections, resulting in the printing of all aliases. From that point onward, it recognized the 'manager' database. If anyone can shed light on the root cause of this, please provide an explanation.